# Error:(31, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'jniDebugBuild()'

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I have updated my Android Studio and I keep getting this error no matter what I do. I imported a project from github everything was running smoothly until I updated now I keep getting this error:

Error:(31, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'jniDebugBuild()'
Possible causes:

The project 'my_application' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The name of this property has changed in v0.14.0 and later of the Android Gradle plugin, so build files created for earlier versions need to be updated. Look through all the **build.gradle** files in the project, and when you see `jniDebugBuild`, change it to `jniDebuggable`.

You may run into other things that need to be renamed; the list of remappings is in the release notes at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system.